# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"menu" | "selectedMenu" | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm making multiple select in typescript, material-ui, React. I need to set `MenuProps.variant = 'menu'`, but I'm facing the error,

*Type '{ variant: string; PaperProps: { style: { maxHeight: number; width: number; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial'.
Types of property 'variant' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"menu" | "selectedMenu" | undefined'.*

for the below code. How to resolve this error?

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  variant: 'menu',
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

const names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'April Tucker',
  'Ralph Hubbard',
  'Omar Alexander',
  'Carlos Abbott',
  'Miriam Wagner',
  'Bradley Wilkerson',
  'Virginia Andrews',
  'Kelly Snyder',
];


export default function MultipleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
    setPersonName(event.target.value as string[]);
  };

  return (
        <Select
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input />}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name} style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      )
}
```

Reference
https://material-ui.com/api/menu/
https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the `MenuProps` type from Material-UI with:

```
import { MenuProps as MenuPropsType } from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
```

Then you can use this like the following:

```
const MenuProps: Partial<MenuPropsType> = {
  variant: "menu",
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250
    }
  }
};
```

You use `Partial<MenuPropsType>` (as it also is in the [Select type definition](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.1/packages/material-ui/src/Select/Select.d.ts#L67)) because `Select` automatically adds the required `open` prop (if you remove `Partial`, it will complain about the `open` prop not being specified).

Here's a working example based on your code:

```
import React from "react";
import { MenuProps as MenuPropsType } from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps: Partial<MenuPropsType> = {
  variant: "menu",
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250
    }
  }
};

const names = [
  "Oliver Hansen",
  "Van Henry",
  "April Tucker",
  "Ralph Hubbard",
  "Omar Alexander",
  "Carlos Abbott",
  "Miriam Wagner",
  "Bradley Wilkerson",
  "Virginia Andrews",
  "Kelly Snyder"
];

export default function MultipleSelect() {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
    setPersonName(event.target.value as string[]);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      multiple
      value={personName}
      onChange={handleChange}
      input={<Input />}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}
    >
      {names.map((name) => (
        <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
          {name}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit MenuProps type]

Answer (score 2):

Because `variant` only receive type is `"menu" | "selectedMenu" | undefined`. But you pass a value is "menu" without type. So it will auto has type is `string`.
You need to define a type for `variant`. Like this:

```
const MenuProps = {
  variant: 'menu' as 'menu',
  ...
};
```